# Get the maximum value from multiple objects in pandas .max()

Tags: python, pandas, syntax-error, max

I have a data set like this:

```
ID   column_1  column_2 column_3 column 4
AAA   0.1        0.6      0.1     0.2
AAA   0.2        0.2      0.2     0.1
BBB   0.5        0.5      0.1     0.1
BBB   0.1        0.3      0.1     0.2
```

```
output = (df['column_1'] – df['column_2']) / (df['column_3'], 5 * df['column_1'], 0.01 * abs(df['column_4'])).max(axis=1)
```

but it gave me an error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

The expected output can be described as this example:
for the first row - output = (0.1 - 0.6) / max(0.1, 5*0.1, 0.01*abs(0.2)) = -0.5/0.5 = -1
Can someone give me some hints? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is join them by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and then use `max` per rows:

```
s = pd.concat([df['column_3'], 
               5 * df['column_1'], 
               0.01 * abs(df['column_4'])], axis=1).max(axis=1)
output = (df['column_1'] - df['column_2']) / s
print (output)
0   -1.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
3   -0.4
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you know what's the issue about my code?

Comment: your output is not correct, for the first row, the output should be -1, not 0.5

Comment: Which typo??I can't see any typo here

Comment: You neglected 'df['column_3'] when comparing the maximum value, and is there any method that I can use in pandas

Comment: I've seen your updates, again, I need to get the maximum value from 3 values not just 2.

Comment: @Cecilia - Mea culpa, I miss it. So solution was edited.

Comment: It works, turns out there is a typo about '-', you are right, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Actually I got a follow-up question, I will get an error is I replace ```df['column_3']``` with an constant number like 1, error ```TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'int'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid```, do you know what the issue here? Thanks.

Comment: @Cecilia - Then change `df['column_3']` to `pd.Series(1, index=df.index)`

Answer (score 1):

Your minus is not really a minus `(df['column_1'] – df['column_2'])`. You have em dash instead en dash.